# Function with return value not error when you just call the function

Tags: c, function, return-value

For function with return value, why does it not error when we just call it like we call a void function?
For example, printf function is for output. But we see here, printf function have a return value.

```
int printf(const char* format, ...) // printf function

#include<string.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Why when we have a return value in a function, we could just call the function without specify what the return value saved to? And what happen to the return value?

Comment: Because the language has been designed like this. If you don't use the return value, nothing happens to the return value, it's simply not used.

Comment: There is no harm in discarding the return value of a function.

Comment: Some people prefer write `(void)printf("Hello");`. Personally, I never ignore return value.

Comment: @Stargateur ... even on `printf`?

Comment: @MichaelWalz When I code function that call `printf`, like something `int print_x_struct(FILE *file, struct x *x)`, this function return the result of printf call (sum of all printf return or -1). But when I use this function with `stdout`, I generally ignore return value... ^^

Comment: @Stargateur OK, but your two comments are somewhat contradictory: _Personally, I never ignore return value_ vs. _... I generally ignore return value_.

Comment: BTW, don't just declare `printf`. Your tool chain may very likely have specific attributes on it, increasing the likelyhood this is you shooting yourself in the foot. Include `stdio.h` instead.

Comment: The reason is that compilers are traditionally extra-sloppy when using the stdio.h functions. Many compilers don't warn when you skip the return value of printf/scanf, to the point where implicitly ignoring the return value has become de facto standard. Pretty much everything revolving around printf/scanf is an orgy in bad programming practice. Why stdio.h is often banned from production-quality code.

Comment: "why does it not error when we just call it like we call a void function?" Why should there be an error? A plain expression is a valid statement. A function return value is just as much an expression as `5` or `i` are. Not very useful but fine according to standard. OTOH, some tools like Coverity Prevent throw a finding at you if you ignore return values.

Answer (score 4):

> And what happen to the return value?

It's discarded, ignored.

> Why when we have a return value in a function, we could just call the function without specify what the return value saved to?

Because that's what the language designers deemed appropriate. Seems foolish to you, but that return value isn't always guaranteed to be useful. In the case of `printf` the value indicates how many characters were written. And we may care about it to detect any errors. But if we do any printing as part of error handling itself, what good is that value? Are we going to fail even harder now?
 We should be able to ignore it without introducing an unused variable.

And just in case you want your compiler to warn you about ignoring the value, most have compilation switches to that effect. For example, GCC's `-Wunused-result`.

In that case, you can make the discarding explicit by casting the result to `void`. Some say it expresses intent better, but YMMV.